# cocos2d vector with CallFunc callbacks. Losing memory

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I got vector at mainScene:

```
std::vector<CallFunc*> callbacksToSchedule;
```

At init() method:

```
auto updateCallBack = CallFunc::create([](){log("hello");});
updateCallBack->setTag(100);
callbacksToSchedule.push_back(updateCallBack);
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->schedule([this](float dt) {
                                                      for(auto callFunc: callbacksToSchedule){
                                                          log(std::to_string(callFunc->getTag()).c_str());
                                                          callFunc->execute();
                                                      }
                                                  }, this,
                   RESOURCES_UPDATE_TIME, true, "schedulerKey");
```

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

And output:

> 1952803683

But should be:

> 100

Answer (score 0):

`updateCallBack` released when the `init()` ends.  purged from memory because retainCount is zero. When you need them in an instance variable you've to retain them.

```
auto updateCallBack = CallFunc::create([](){log("hello");});
updateCallBack->setTag(100);
updateCallBack->retain();                      // retain updateCallBack
callbacksToSchedule.push_back(updateCallBack);
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->schedule([this](float dt) {

        for(auto callFunc: callbacksToSchedule){
            CCLOG("%d TAG VALUE",callFunc->getTag());
            callFunc->execute();
        }
    }, this,RESOURCES_UPDATE_TIME, true, "schedulerKey");
```